# How to make project snapshots in android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and to Android Development as well. I am presently using version 1.3.1.

My question is how to **efficiently** make project "snapshots". - I am not absolutely sure the term of "snapshot" is good hence the quotes.

What I mean is to save the project as is at the moment and be able to make heavy changes without fearing to destroy what is already working well and also to be able to restart from this "snapshot" if it happens that the changes made break the project.

In other terms, how can I manage versions?

Comment: you need to use a version control system. lookup `git`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a version control program such as `git` or `svn`, although `git` tends to be the industry standard tool.

You can follow a very simple [online tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) to get started quickly with the basics behind `git`. There are also a number of other excellent resources such as the [git guide by Tower](http://git-tower.com/learn) and the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

In regards to versioning, you can use `git tag` to tag specific versions (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging))

```
#Create a new tag
git tag -a v1.0 -m 'Version 1.0'

#Create a new working branch 'version_2_dev' from v1.0
git checkout -b version_2_dev v1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit intimidated on learning tools such as git at first and specially on how it interfaces with the IDE but after looking at the online tutorial you suggest and the other two videos hereafter mentioned I now feel more confident. The integration in Android-studio seems rather good.https://www.londonappdeveloper.com  /how-to-clone-a-github-project-on-android-studio/   https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

Comment: Glad to hear it @meaulnes. It looks and sounds intimidating, but is truly one of the most useful tools available for developers. It is worth taking the time to learn the basics.

Comment: For other questioners I also found this very clear introduction : https://www.git-tower.com/learn/ and at the moment I have started reading the git book http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2. Both are very good reference I think.

Comment: @meaulnes I will add these to my answer. If my answer helped answer your question, please feel free to mark it as an accepted answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the version control plug-ins like bitbucket, svn and git.